# Can a 10uf Capacitor be used in place of a 15uf capacitor temporarily?

Tags: capacitor, hvac

I am in Phoenix and it's hot. The indoor blower motor just went out on our AC unit and the wife and kids are not happy. It is just a bad capacitor.

Original capacitor is 15uf 440v. I was able to get one on Amazon that will be here in two days but it is only **10uf** 440v. Will this be alright for a week or two until I can get my hands on a 15uf 440v capacitor or is it dangerous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a starting cap? Reading around...no it reduces the life of your motor.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is a starting capacitor. The motor is old anyway and will probably need to be replaced as well. Just looking to keep the family cool for a week or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be fine for a temporary role, it means the phase shift of the motor is a little off, so you can expect lower output power / torque than usual, a larger capacitance would be what might cause damage.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your response!

Comment: Draft inducer fan on our furnace failed because the run cap dropped in value (as they do, due to self-healing) and it stalled/overheated and the coils shorted.

Comment: @MattCashatt Yeah, from what I read an oversized cap runs the motor too hard, but an undersized caps underpowers the motor which can make it stall and overheat all the same.